# problem in costructing gaussian random distribution in a range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, gaussian

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFeSP.png)

```
from random import seed
from random import random
from random import gauss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
NUM = []
seed(1)
for i in range(10000):

    num = min(10, max(0, gauss(4, 2)))
    NUM.append(num)

plt.hist(NUM, bins = 100) 
plt.show()
```

> But, as shown in picture, there are lots of samples at "0" how to
> reduce that ?

Comment: Any values below `0` are increased to `0` by your use of `max` (and values above `10` are decreased to `10` by your use of `min` but there are fewer so it's less obvious). Why are you doing this? If you want to limit the range of values shown in the graph just discard these values rather than changing them?

Comment: @IainShelvington in that case, sample size of 10000 will be compromised. isn't it ?

Comment: If you don't want to lose data then remove the limits

Comment: @IainShelvington In that case it would be like I am sacking "a part" of the actual gaussian distribution. Whereas I want to store the entire distribution ranging between these tow points.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a truncated normal distribution, the simplest solution in my opinion is just to discard the values that are out of the defined range and try again.

```
for i in range(10000):
    num = gauss(4, 2)
    while num<0 and num>10:
        num = gauss(4, 2)
    NUM += [num]
```